# How to update unread messages counter live in a React chat app when another user writes you

Tags: reactjs, .net, asp.net-core, fetch-api

I made a react chat app but the unread-messages-counter (just like on Facebook) only updates when I refresh the app and fetch data again from the server. What is the best way to do this? I am using a .NET Core API and MS SQL Server. I could theoretically check every 10 seconds for new messages via fetch but that does not sound like the smartest option to me.

Comment: Hi @timo, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 1):

> I made a react chat app but the unread-messages-counter (just like on facebook) only updates when I refresh the app and fetch data again from the server.

ASP.NET Core SignalR can be used to add real-time web functionality to apps easily, and real-time chat application is often used as an example in doc.

To achieve your requirement, you can add a hub server and call client method to push messages to all client users or specific user(s), then you can dynamically update UI to change unread-messages-counter on react client side. To get started with ASP.NET Core SignalR, you can check following documents.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: In [this case](https://forums.asp.net/t/2140825.aspx?facebook+like+notification+lin+MVC5), I shared a sample of implementing facebook like notification using Signalr, you can refer to it and achieve same based on your actual requirement.

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75220565/how-to-do-when-msg-is-readed-then-color-is-change-or-msg-is-nor-read-its-color

Answer (score 0):

You can use websockets or like you said, poll the information every n seconds. Intergrating websockets may require a redesign of your app architecture however it will provide better performance and ux since updates will be real-time.

Websockets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#:~:text=WebSocket%20is%20a%20computer%20communications,WebSocket%20is%20distinct%20from%20HTTP.

Comment: Thank you, I never knew what a websocket is. Maybe its time to find out :)